# When to use identity comparison instead of equals?

Tags: object-oriented, comparison

I wonder why would anybody want to use identity comparison for fields in `equals`, like here (Java syntax):

```
class C {
    private A a;

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        // standard boring prelude
        if (other==this) return true;
        if (other==null) return false;
        if (other.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
        C c = (C) other;

        // the relevant part
        if (c.a != this.a) return false;

        // more tests... and then
        return true;
    }

    // getter, setters, hashCode, ...
}
```

Using `==` is a bit faster than `equals` and a bit shorter (due to no need for null tests), too, but in what cases (if any) you'd say it's really better **to use `==` for fields inside `equals`**?

Comment: Should this be tagged as Java specific?  The answer is language dependent. (See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx for details about C#...)

Comment: @tugs: To me it looks now like C# has two things roughly equivalent to Java's equals, whereby one of the doesn't really work (due to missing overloading). My question is primarily about identity (pointer) comparison vs. content comparison, so it's not that Java specific. I know virtually nothing about C#, but I'm pretty sure the question applies to C++ as well.

Comment: @tugs: Now I'm imagining /b/ on MSDN.

Comment: This is definitely language-specific. For example, Java does some optimization tricks with strings, to avoid keeping redundant copies in memory; as a result, you can wind up with a situation where you think you instantiated two strings, but they're actually represented by the same object. And C++ has operator overloading, which completely changes everything.

Comment: @Mike Baranczak: What Java does to Strings doesn't matter in the context of my question *as I meant it* (which doesn't match well what I wrote). In C++ `virtual operator==` gets used in place of java's `equals` and pointer comparison gets used in place of java's `==`, so I see there more or less 1:1 correspondence. But feel free to add the tag if you're confident it belongs there.

Comment: Have you read [Methods common to all objects](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy252/project_old/Chapter3.pdf)? For many classes, it does not even make sense to override equals in the first place, especially if those classes are mutable.

Comment: Also, having a *virtual* `operator==` in C++ is an extremely bad idea. Every C++ programmer worth his salt will tell you that. Inheritance and equivalence just do not mix well.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I was never claiming that it makes sense to *always* override equals. Using `virtual operator==` directly corresponds with Java, as it's `equals` is always virtual; if it makes sense in C++ is a different story.

Answer (score 2):

There are cases when checking for instance equality with `==` is necessary. For example, that is what you do in the implementation of `equals` to check if you are comparing an object to itself (a very important shortcut that also satisfies the reflexivity requirement of `equals`)

```
if (other==this) return true;
```

The other case is when the system guarantees that there will be only one instance that is equal to any object of a particular class (and by necessity that is going to be the instance itself - again, due to reflexivity of `equals`). This is another common case illustrated by your code fragment:

```
if (other.getClass() != this.getClass())
```

An equality of two `java.lang.Class` objects is equivalent to the equality of their references, because for each class that you define there is one, and only one, instance of `java.lang.Class`.

A third case where reference equality is desired is serialization: you need to keep track of object instances by tracking their references, even if they are logically equal, in order to be able to produce an isomorphic graph upon deserialization.

**EDIT :** Inside implementations of `equals` the use of `==` boils down to increasing performance: comparing an object to itself is a common case, especially when you use objects of the class as keys in a hash table, so it makes sense to optimize it.

Comment: I see that my question isn't very clear (and I still don't know how to make it better). Your first two cases are just optimizations; I could have left `other==this` out and I could have used `equals` for the class comparison (as it's actually the same). The serialization case is an important one. But when would you *inside equals* compare two *fields of an object* via `==` for a reason other than performance?

Comment: @maaartinus Ah, I see what you mean after the edit. Please see the update to the answer.

Comment: Two more situations where `==` is appropriate are when an object (such as `IdentityHashMap`) has received objects from outside code which expects them to be compared with `==`, or when a method acts upon two objects, at least one of which is received by outside code and the other of which has been exposed to outside code, and it needs to ensure that in fact has two distinct objects, rather than two references to the same one.

Answer (score 1):

The `== operator` in Java checks for reference equality: it returns true if the pointers are the same. It does not check for contents equality.

Use the equals() method to compare object values. 
The equals() method returns a boolean value.

The two operators that can be used with object references are comparing for `equality (==)` and `inequality (!=).` These operators compare two values to see if they refer to the same object. Although this comparison is very fast, it is often not what you want.
Usually you want to know if the objects have the same value, and not whether two objects are a reference to the same object. For example,

```
if (name == "My Test Value")   // Legal, but ALMOST SURELY WRONG
```

This is true only if name is a reference to the same object that "My Test Value" refers to. This will be false if the String in name was read from input or computed (by putting strings together or taking the substring), even though name really does have exactly those characters in it.

Many classes (eg, String) define the `equals()` method to **compare the values of objects.**

Comment: It appears OP already knows that, and in any case this does not address the question which was asked. -1

Comment: @delnan, i did not finish my answer. Now it is more or less completed.

Comment: Fair enough, downvote removed. Though I do find it strange to "not finish an answer" before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that very often we use `==` instead of `equals()` only for performance, where calling `equals()` would do just as well, but there exist cases where using `==` is necessary.

For example, if you have a list which allows duplicate values, (multiple different instances that appear equal according to their `equals()` methods,) and you want to remove a particular instance from that list, you cannot use `equals()` to find the instance to remove, because `equals()` would find you the first duplicate, not the exact instance that you are looking for.  To find the exact instance, you *must* use `==`.

Of course, this is just a simplistic example. In order to find out more about why both `==` and `equals()` are absolutely necessary, you need to read up on the concept of *value semantics vs. reference semantics*.  (I searched for some good source of information on the subject but could not find anything well written; if someone finds something good, please post!)

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed rare when you want to do reference (`==`) equality instead of logical (`equals()`) equality. Often when you find yourself checking for reference equality, there might be something wrong with your design, or you might want to implement the `equals()` method.

Nevertheless, there is one case where I often check for reference equality (not sure if that's good practice):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    AbstractButton source = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();

    if (source == someButton)
        doStuff();
    else if (source == someOtherButton)
        doSomethingElse();
    // ...
}
```