# Reasons to want false-negatives when comparing strings (or string references)?

Tags: java, c#, language-design, language-features

Java programmers know that `new String("some-text") == new String("some-text")` evaluates to false because two different objects/references are being compared [and that `String.equals` should be used to compare Strings instead].

So, can you think of any reasons why a person may want to see false for comparing different pointers to the same string value?

One reason why that 'feature' may exist in Java is so that it's not different from other equality comparisons. But, that's not a reason why people may want to see false for that comparison.

I'm not sure there is any actually applicability to this besides future language designs. =/
(Some languages already have special first-class comparison for strings, but this question isn't a knock at Java.)

Edit 1: Based on the comments, I can re-phrase the question to hopefully clarify a bit more: **What are some use cases for wanting false-negatives when comparing strings (or references to strings)?** (This makes it more language-agnostic too, where the comparison might be Java's == or C#'s referenceEquals)

Edit 2: Thanks to @RobertHarvey, there's another way I can clarify the question and the answer I'm looking for: Comparing references to strings can be used to know (1) whether or not the two strings are two different objects, and perhaps (2) whether or not a string is interned. Knowing that, **the ultimate question is (1.1) what's some use cases for wanting to know whether or not it's two different string objects when the string value is the same? (1.2) what's some use cases for wanting to know if a string is interned or not?** ...looking for answers with a language-user perspective and not the language-developer perspective (like debugging language implementation). ;)

Edit 3: Thanks to MichaelT, caveats for Java 8 String Deduplication.

Edit 4: To be more straight-forward: For this particular question, I don't care about why any `==` operators are the way that they are. I don't care about workarounds. There are other questions that talk about those issues.  So, another rephrasing of the question to maybe help clarify: When would a developer want to perform an action when getting 'false' from comparing different string references of same string value? Interned string comparison works to perform an action when true. I'm looking for the 'false' side of things. If nobody can think of any real use-cases/reasons, then I'm okay with there not being an answer to this question. (And, to rule out a potential answer from that.. you don't *need* to check for false to do an iterative comparison or attempt to intern a string)

--

Meta: Here's a [similar question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/167684/when-to-use-identity-comparison-instead-of-equals/167685#167685) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/193638/why-didnt-operator-string-value-comparison-make-it-to-java/193706) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/193638/why-didnt-operator-string-value-comparison-make-it-to-java), but they elicits answers that are different from this specific question, like what is already mentioned above.

Comment: `Can you think of any reasons why a person may want to see false for comparing different pointers to the same string value?`  -- Because they're two different objects.  In C#, `==` is overloaded to yield the result that makes more sense and is more useful (comparison of two strings, not their references), and most duplicate strings are *interned,* so they really are the same string, even by reference.  If you still want to compare references, you can use `object.ReferenceEquals()`.